# Simple SUM for 2 field values - lotus notes

Tags: sum, lotus-notes, field

I have two fields: number1, number2. They are editable.

I have another computed field number 3. In its default value I coded: number1+number2. It isn't working

Answer (score 2):

You have it set up correctly. However, you haven't triggered the computation.  To do that you would need to:

- save the form
- press a button that runs the command ViewRefreshFields
- change number one and two to be dialog lists that have the option set to refresh fields on keyword change.
- write some client JavaScript code and handle the onchange event for the number fields

UPDATE:

I believe the js code would be:

```
var form = document.forms[0];
form.number3.value = form.number1.value + form.number2.value;
```

Comment: and that "some code" will be?... It thought it will be a much simpler way

Comment: The F9 key (and F5 nowadays) will update computed fields, out of the box

Answer (score 1):

If this is for the Notes client and your form is simple (without a lot of lookups or complex computations), then there is a simple property called "Automatically refresh fields" on the Info tab of the Form Properties.  That should trigger the computation without any extra coding.

However, I found this IBM [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21099674) which mentions some circumstances where this property does not work, but gives a potential workaround.